# Z-Ordering for side by side fixed divs

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website with a fixed header which has a fixed bar at the top, and then a vertical nav bar that is attached to it. To see what I mean click here: http://crag.stmarkssheffield.co.uk
The code for this looks something like

CSS:

```
#top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu{
    text-align: left;
    width: 175px;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #4d4d4d;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    float: left;
}

#user{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:0.865em;
}
#main{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='top'>
    <div style="font-size: 60px; border-color: #4d4d4d; border-bottom-style:solid; border-width:3px; background: white">ST MARKS CRAG<div style="font-size: 20px">A breath of fresh air</div></div>
        <span id='user' style="padding-top: 0; margin-top: 0">
            [@usertext]
        </span>
        <span id="menu" style="background: white">
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Home</a></p>
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">My data</a></p>
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">About</a></p>
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Members stories</a></p>
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Useful Links</a></p>
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Report a problem</a></p>
            <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Contact</a></p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='main'>
        <div class = "bubble">
                TEST
        </div>
</div>
```

Now the issue is that the browser thinks that the nav bar is rendered in front of the main content, that starts next to it, and doesn't let me interact with the main content. If I put the z-index of the main content higher, then I can't interact with the nav bar, what should I do?

Comment: The menu on the left, and the header should be two seperate entities, not joined together like you have it

Comment: @tw16 I mean I can't select text or click links in it. The link was temporarily broken while I tried the answer.

Comment: Ok. So now the layout is the same in all the browsers. But I am having no issues selecting the "TEST" text and all of the links on the sidebar work.

Comment: @tw16 Yes. I fixed it :P I'm about to submit my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this it is necessary to use to top, bottom, left and right css rules. The revised CSS is this:

```
#header{
    background:white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #4d4d4d;
}

#menu{
    background: white;
    text-align: left;
    width: 175px;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #4d4d4d;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 94px;
    position: fixed
}

#user{
    top: 94px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:15px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And the html:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>ST MARKS CRAG</h1>
    <h2>A breath of fresh air</h2>
</div>
<div id="user">
    [@usertext]
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Home</a></p>
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">My data</a></p>
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">About</a></p>
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Members stories</a></p>
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Useful Links</a></p>
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Report a problem</a></p>
    <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Contact</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have it something like this instead...

```
<div id='top'>
<div style="font-size: 60px; border-color: #4d4d4d; border-bottom-style:solid; border-width:3px; background: white">ST MARKS CRAG<div style="font-size: 20px">A breath of fresh air</div>
</div>

 <div id='main'>

     <div id="menu" style="background: white">
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Home</a></p>
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">My data</a></p>
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">About</a></p>
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Members stories</a></p>
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Useful Links</a></p>
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Report a problem</a></p>
        <p>&emsp;<a href="#">Contact</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class = "bubble">
            TEST
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then the nav bar and the div containing the user text aren't fixed, and if I set them to fixed, the one on the right doesn't float right.